# Using Django URL parameters in JavaScript inner HTML fails

Tags: javascript, json, django, ajax, django-templates

I am trying to dynamically change the innerHTML of a Django template using Javascript.
There are some anchor tags inside the HTML content. Their href contains Django URL with some parameters. There is some issue with it, but can't figure it out.
$.ajax({
url: "{%url 'fact:datalist' %}",
type: 'POST',
headers: {
"X-CSRFToken": token,
},
dataType: 'json',
data: {
csrfmiddlewaretoken: token,
seldata: selectedDate,
}
}).done(function (data) {
const pdata = JSON.parse(data)

```
        pdata.forEach((key, index) => {
            const val = key.fields;
            console.log(val)

            const nid = val.result_id;

            trdata = `<tr>
                <td>${index}</td>
                <td style="display: none;"> ${nid} </td>
                <td><a href="{%url 'fact:entry_form' id=${nid} %}"> ${val.pdtcode} </a></td>
                <td> ${val.process_code} </td>
                <td> ${val.prev_count} </td>
                <td> ${val.ok_count} </td>
                <td> ${val.ng_count} `;
            if (val.ng_count != 0) {
                trdata = `<br><a href="{%url 'fact:editform' id=${nid} %}"> Edit </a>`;
            }
            trdata = `</td>
                <td> ${val.unattended_count}`;
            if (val.unattended_count != 0) {
                trdata = `<br><a href="{%url 'fact:checkform' id=${nid} %}"> Check </a>`;
            }
            trdata = `</td>
            </tr>`;

            $('.data_view>tbody').html(trdata)
        });
    })
}
```

The issue exists at the id=${nid} part of every URL.
Need some advice to tackle this issue.
Thanks in advance